# Existence of a subsequence such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \|x_{n_k}-x\|=\ell>0$ in a Banach space?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces

Let $x_n$ be a sequence in a uniformly convex Banach space $E$ such that $x_n \to x$ weakly in $E$ and $\|x_n\|_E \to \|x\|_E$. Then $x_n \to x$ strongly in $E$.

To show this by contradiction a proof I'm reading states that first we suppose that (for the non-trivial $x\neq 0$ case)
$$
\limsup_{n\to \infty} \|x_n-x\|>0.
$$
Then there exists a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ such that
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \|x_{n_k}-x\|=\ell>0.
$$
My question is how can we say there exists such a subsequence that converges to a finite number? I don't see anything in the assumptions that gives us this?

Comment: This is a property of the real line, not $E$. If the limit supremum of your sequence is finite, then there is an upper bound on all of the terms beyond some index $N$. Any bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ has a convergent subsequence. In particular, if the limit supremum exists, then we can choose a subsequence that converges to the limit supremum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point at which you seem to have a question is not about Banach spaces; it's about sequences of real numbers. You have a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ of real numbers for which
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n >0
$$
and the question is: how does this imply that there is a subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^\infty$ for which
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty} a_{n_k} = \ell>0.
$$
If you have $\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n = \ell>0,$ then how do you show there is a subsequence converging to $\ell\text{?}$

**First approach:**
Apply the definition of $\limsup:$
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n = \inf\left\{ \sup\{a_n,a_{n+1},a_{n+2}, a_{n+3}, \ldots\} : n\in\{1,2,3,\ldots\} \right\} = \ell >0.
$$
This means every number $h<\ell$ fails to be a lower bound of the sequence
$$
\Big\{ \sup\{a_n,a_{n+1},a_{n+2}, \ldots\} \Big\}_{n=1}^\infty.
$$
Failure of $h$ to be a lower bound of this sequence means some member of this sequence is $>h.$ Thus we have
$$
\forall h<\ell\  \exists n\  \sup\{a_n,a_{n+1},a_{n+2},\ldots\} > h.
$$
Just let $n_k$ be some index $\ge n$ for which $a_{n_k}>h.$

**Second approach:** Relying on a definition of $\limsup,$ show that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n = \ell$ if and only if $\ell$ is the largest of all limits of subsequences of $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty.$ That implies there is some subsequence converging to $\ell.$

Comment: Related answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493526/can-someone-clearly-explain-about-the-lim-sup-and-lim-inf/493650#493650

Answer (score 3):

Since $\|x_n\| \to \|x\|$ it follows that the real sequence $\{ \|x_n-x\|\}_{n\geq 1}$ is bounded which implies that the $\limsup_{n\to \infty} \|x_n-x\|$ is finite.
Then the existence of the subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}_{k\geq 1}$ follows from the [definition of $\limsup$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior#Definition_for_sequences) (for a sequence of real numbers).